# Tweepy get date user created twitter account

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I tried Tweepy to get data from twitter but I have a problem when I want to get the date of user when he/she created Twitter account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up your twitter oauth 
and then use JSON raw parser

```
api = tweepy.API(auth_handler=auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())
user_data = api.get_user(screen_name)
```

on your data that you get, you will see `user_data['created_at']`

Answer (score 0):

```
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api = API(auth)

print 'Getting statistics for @user:'

# Get information about the user
data = api.get_user('user')
print str(data.created_at)
```

Hope That Help :)